# infix to postfix converter, not outputting right answer

Tags: java, converters, infix-notation, rpn

I got a school-project where I was given this information:

```
for i=1 to m
if c_i is an operand: Transfer c_i to output.
if c_i is a left parentheses: Push c_i to tmp.
if c_i is a right parentheses: Pop elements from tmp and transfer
them to output until a left-parentheses
is met. Pop left-parentheses.
if c_i is an operator: Let the top tmp element be t. Pop and
transfer elements from tmp to output
until:
p(t) < p(c_i) or
t is a left-parentheses or
tmp is empty.
Push c_i to tmp.
Transfer the remaining elements in tmp to output.
```

I have been doing exactly these steps, but my output only gets right som times. I guess that Im thinking wrong somewhere around the if statement with the operators. I've constantly been debugging for 2 days now, and I just cant find the solution.

I would be very pleased if someone would like to check my code. The operatorCheck function is made for solving this: "We use the subroutine p to specify the priorities of the operators:

```
p(+) = 0,
p(−) = 0, p(∗) = 1, p(/) = 1
```

. This means that addition and subtraction have
lower priority compared to multiplication and division."

Code: http://pastebin.com/TA7UGiGc

Thank you!

Comment: I'm comparing your code with mine to see where the error is coming. Stay put. By the way, this question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! oh, sorry I was not aware of that :/ @Mr.Robot

Comment: You need to debug your `else if` in which it checks whether the `char` is an operator or not. My suggestion is you should make 2 different `else if` for operators `+` `-` and `*` `/`

Comment: Okay, @Mr.Robot I'll try that... I've been debugging it for 2 days now :p, but I'll try to split them up to 2 statements instead of 1!

Comment: can you include an input string with wrong output and what output should be returned?

Comment: input: 5+5*5*(2+10) output should be: 555*210+*+ my ouput: 55+5*210+* @dtortola

Comment: @MarcoKoivisto I did this program in java but instead of numbers,I have operands as a,b,c,d,e ....z

Comment: @MarcoKoivisto Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping and removing the first letter from `tmp` without getting the next letter to compare with in the while loop, therefore you need to get a new character inside the while loop.

The substring is also removing the wrong characters from `tmp`, it should keep everything except the first letter and that's accomplished with `tmp.substring(1, tmp.length())`

I have fixed that block of code below:

```
else if (character == '+' || character == '-' || character == '*' || character == '/'){
    while (true) {
        char t = tmp.length() > 0 ? tmp.charAt(0): ' ';
        if (operatorCheck(t) < operatorCheck(character) || t == '(' || tmp.length() < 0) {
            break;
        }

        output += t;
        tmp = tmp.substring(1, tmp.length());
    }
    tmp = character + tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marco, in your code, the line 42

```
while (tmp.length() > 0 && !(operatorCheck(t) > operatorCheck(character)) && t != '(')
```

you have to change > with <

In the algorithm, the exit conditions are

```
tmp.length()==0 || p(t) < p(c_i) || t=='('
```

Since it's a while you have to negate that

```
!(tmp.length()==0 || p(t) < p(c_i) || t=='(')
===
(tmp.length()>0 && p(t) >= p(c_i) && t!='(')
=== (to write it with ! as you did)
(tmp.length()>0 && !(p(t) < p(c_i)) && t!='(')
```

Besides this, Dante is right about using stacks. If you want to avoid the autoboxing problem you can make your own primitive stack class for char

Comment: doing it with the : while (tmp.length() > 0 && !(operatorCheck(t) < operatorCheck(character)) && t!='('){ Gives me the same output as before :/